# What is the loss of data in 'uintmax_t' to 'size_t' and 'unsigned int' conversion?

Tags: c++, boost, int

I get this:

> warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'uintmax_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data

on:

```
boost::shared_array<char> buffer( new char[file->size]);
```

…and then this:

> warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'uintmax_t' to 'size_t', possible loss of data

on:

```
boost::asio::write(*socket, boost::asio::buffer(buffer.get(), file->size));
```

Shall I be scared or it is ok?

Answer (score 5):

Probably `file->size` is of type `uintmax_t` which is larger than the `size_t` that `operator new[]` takes for the array size. Typically the first one could be a 64bit integer while the second one would only be a 32bit.

Practically this will lead to problems when you are trying to handle files over 4GB, because the `size_t` can't represent such a large number of bytes. If you only expect to handle smaller files where `size_t` is large enough to store the file size, there won't be a problem.

Comment: "Practically this will lead to problems when you are trying to handle files over 4GB" That's making an assumption that `size_t` is 32 bit when it could be larger, which means it's incorrect for the general case.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the implementation.

`uintmax_t` is the largest unsigned type provided by the implementation.  `size_t` is the type of the result of the `sizeof` operator, big enough to hold the size of any object.  `unsigned int` is, of course, the unsigned version of the type `int`.

The only guarantees are that `size_t` and `unsigned int` are both at least 16 bits (but likely to be bigger), `uintmax_t` is at least 64 bits (assuming C99 rules), and `uintmax_t` is at least as wide as any other unsigned type.

Presumably `file->size` is the size in bytes of a file, and it's probably of type `uintmax_t`.  Depending on the system, the maximum size of a file may well be bigger than the size of any possible object in memory.

If the size of this particular file isn't too big, there's no problem.  But if `size_t` is 32 bits (implying objects can't be bigger than 4 gigabytes), and your file is, say, 5 gigabytes, then you won't be able to allocate an in-memory buffer big enough to hold the contents of the file.

And the maximum value of `size_t`, `SIZE_MAX`, is only an upper bound on the maximum size of an object.  Just because `SIZE_MAX` is 2**31-1, that doesn't necessarily mean you can actually create an object that big.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how big your files are.

Most computers have larger disk storage than RAM, and in many cases can support a single file too large to fit into RAM.  In such a case, the allocation may fail, or the file size may be truncated to the size of a pointer, in which case you'll allocate a buffer which is not large enough to hold the file.

You can detect files of excessive size with:

```
size_t buffersize(file->size);
if (buffersize != file->size) { /* error, file too large to fit into virtual memory */ }
/* use buffersize for buffer allocation */
```

This would also make the warnings go away.