# can anyone explain why size_t type is used with an example?

Tags: c++, c

I was wondering why this `size_t` is used where I can use say int type. Its said that `size_t` is a return type of `sizeof` operator. What does it mean? like if I use `sizeof(int)` and store what its return to an `int` type variable, then it also works, it's not necessary to store it in a `size_t` type variable. I just clearly want to know the basic concept of using `size_t` with a clearly understandable example.Thanks

Comment: You can use an int to store the return of sizeof in the same way that you can sometimes store 2147483647 in an int. It just so happens that the implementation specific sizes match up correctly.

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918787/whats-sizeofsize-t-on-32-bit-vs-the-various-64-bit-data-models

Comment: Can anyone confirm that size_t is the same size of the processor registers?

Comment: @arthurprs It's not. `int_fastN_t` is more likely, but still not.

Comment: @arthurprs: often it's so, but nothing mandates it. For example, you may have a platform with a limited (e.g. 16 bit) address space but 32 bit computing capabilities: here the sensible size for `size_t` would be 16 bit, while the registers would probably be 32 bit.

Comment: Example of a practical use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645168/how-to-write-a-stdbitset-template-that-works-on-32-and-64-bit

Comment: Well, as you say, the return type of `sizeof` is `size_t`. You seem to be confused by the fact that types are *convertible* in C++. For example, `double x = 'a';` is possible, even though the type of `'a'` is `char`.

Comment: ya,i know,but in the latter case I would see the ascii code of a which is not as same as the effect we see using size_t and int...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`size_t` is guaranteed to be able to represent the largest size possible, `int` is not. This means `size_t` is more portable.

For instance, what if `int` could only store up to 255 but you could allocate arrays of 5000 bytes? Clearly this wouldn't work, however with `size_t` it will.

Comment: Technically `int` has to be at least 16 bits, as it has to span at least the range [-32767..32767].  (Why not -32768?  To accommodate ones'-complement and sign-and-magnitude systems, in case anyone wants to use C on an old Univac machine.  Of course those have 18- and 36-bit integers, with 9-bit `char`.)

Comment: @torek For some reason I'm under the impression that int is only required to be > 16 in C, not C++. Haven't checked the standard though.

Comment: @Pubby: C++ inherits that from C. 1.1 p2 <quote>C++ is a general purpose programming language based on the C programming language as described in ISO/IEC 9899:1999 Programming languages </quote>

Comment: @LokiAstari: [That doesn't mean C++ "inherits" anything](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8594186/560648).

Comment: Technically size can't be negative, so we would get twice as much. Lesson learned: don't use signed types for unsigned values, and don't use (any) int for size.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest example is pretty dated: on an old 16-bit-`int` system with 64 k of RAM, the value of an `int` can be anywhere from -32768 to +32767, but after:

```
char buf[40960];
```

the buffer `buf` occupies 40 kbytes, so `sizeof buf` is too big to fit in an `int`, and it needs an `unsigned int`.

The same thing can happen today if you use 32-bit `int` but allow programs to access more than 4 GB of RAM at a time, as is the case on what are called "I32LP64" models (32 bit `int`, 64-bit `long` and pointer).  Here the type `size_t` will have the same range as `unsigned long`.

Answer (score 1):

You use size_t mostly for casting pointers into unsigned integers of the same size, to perform calculations on pointers as if they were integers, that would otherwise be prevented at compile time.  Such code is intended to compile and build correctly in the context of different pointer sizes, e.g. 32-bit model versus 64-bit.

Comment: *You use size_t mostly for casting pointers into unsigned integers of the same size, to perform calculations on pointers as if they were integers*  No, you don't.  That's what `[u]intptr_t` is for.  There's no guarantee that a pointer will fit into a `size_t`.

Answer (score 0):

It is implementation defined but on 64bit systems you will find that `size_t` is often 64bit while `int` is still 32bit (unless it's [ILP64 or SILP64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit#64-bit_data_models) model).

Answer (score 0):

depending on what architecture you are on (16-bit, 32-bit or 64-bit) an int could be a different size.

if you want a specific size I use uint16_t or uint32_t .... You can check out this thread for more information

[What does the C++ standard state the size of int, long type to be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/size-of-int-long-etc)

Answer (score 0):

*size_t* is a typedef defined to store object size. It can store the maximum object size that is supported by a target platform. This makes it portable.

For example:

```
void * memcpy(void * destination, const void * source, size_t num);
```

*memcpy()* copies *num* bytes from source into destination. The maximum number of bytes that can be copied depends on the platform. So, making *num* as type *size_t* makes *memcpy* portable.

Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7706240/2820412 for further details.

Answer (score 0):

1. size_t is a typedef for one of the fundamental unsigned integer types. It could be unsigned int, unsigned long, or unsigned long long depending on the implementation.
2. Its special property is that it can represent the size of (in bytes) of any object (which includes the largest object possible as well!). That is one of the reasons it is widely used in the standard library for array indexing and loop counting (that also solves the portability issue). Let me illustrate this with a simple example.

Consider a vector of length 2*UINT_MAX, where UINT_MAX denotes the maximum value of unsigned int (which is 4294967295 for my implementation considering 4 bytes for unsigned int).

> std::vector vec(2*UINT_MAX,0);

If you would want to fill the vector using a for-loop such as this, it would not work because unsigned int can iterate only upto the point UINT_MAX (beyond which it will start again from 0).

> for(unsigned int i = 0; i<2*UINT_MAX; ++i) vec[i] = i;

The solution here is to use size_t since it is guaranteed to represent the size of any object (and therefore our vector vec too!) in bytes. Note that for my implementation size_t is a typedef for unsigned long and therefore its max value = ULONG_MAX = 18446744073709551615 considering 8 bytes.

> for(size_t i = 0; i<2*UINT_MAX; ++i) vec[i] = i;

References: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t